# getting variables instead of text while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping a webpage that does not load any XHR request and all the content are in the page. But when i try to scrape the page with scrapy shell or spiders, i get some variables instead of text. For example look at this page:

```
https://lastsecond.ir/tours/24588-%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%AF-22-%D8%AF%DB%8C-96-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%81%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%86
```

I try this code with scrapy shell :

```
response.css("table a h3 img").extract()
```

The response should be this, like it is in the html response:

```
 <img src="https://lastsecond.ir/site/images/placeholder/hotel.svg" alt="Mehr Reza hotel" class="hotelpic">
```

But i get this :

```
['<img :src="hotel.imageUrl" class="hotelpic" :alt="hotel.name">']
```

And i can't scrape it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the website fetch data from back-end calling or using third party service.

But in this case,the original data you scraped is included in native javascript Statement,then import `regex` module to help filter out or extract the data;finally, leverage `json` module to parse and fetch the data you want.

```
var tourcode ={
"id": 24588,
"title": "تور مشهد 22 دی 96 (از اصفهان)",
"slug": "تور-مشهد-22-دی-96-از-اصفهان",
....
"packages": {
    "bundles": {
{
"308892": {
    "id": 308892,
    "hotels": [
        {
            "id": 1298,
            "bundle_id": 308892,
            "link": "https://lastsecond.ir/hotels/1298-mehr-reza",
            "location_id": 410,
            "location_name": "مشهد",
            "name": "Mehr Reza hotel",
            "grade": {
                "id": 80,
                "name": "هتل آپارتمان",
                "icons": [
                    "fa-building"
                ],
                "count": "0",
                "singleIcon": "<i class=\"fa fa-building large-star\"> <label class=\"orange-text\"></label> </i>"
            },
            "decoratedGrade": "<div class=\"d-inline-block ltr hotelGrade\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"left\" title=\"هتل آپارتمان\"><i class=\"fa fa-building orange-text\"></i></div>",
            "score": 0,
            "imageUrl": "https://lastsecond.ir/site/images/placeholder/hotel.svg",
            "reviewsCount": 0,
            "decoratedScore": "<div class=\"hotelScore\"><div class=\"score\" style=\"width: 0%\"></div></div>",
            "description": "صبحانه",
            "service_id": 2,
            "service": "bb",
            "serviceName": "B.B",
            "serviceDesc": "با صبحانه",
            "ordering": "1"
        }
    ],
    "prices": {
        "1": {
            "1": "295000"
        },
        "2": {
            "1": "370000"
        },
        "3": {
            "1": "295000"
        },
        "4": {
            "1": "240000"
        }
    }
}
}
...
    }}
        }
```

And I found a nice post about how to [Extract Data from Native JS statement](https://blog.michaelyin.info/2017/11/20/scrapy-tutorial-11-how-to-extract-data-from-native-javascript-statement/) for your reference.

Assuming operated with scrapy shell

```
$ scrapy shell https://lastsecond.ir/tours/24588-%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B1-%D9%85%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%AF-22-%D8%AF%DB%8C-96-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%81%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%86
 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
 ....
$ import re
$ import json
$ jsonstr = re.findall("var tourcode = (.+?);\n",response.body.decode('utf-8'),re.S)
$ jsonobj = json.loads(jsonstr[0])
# parse json object here
```

Comment: I use this code but o don't get the proper encoded text: `with codecs.open('lastsecond/page.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(jsonstr[0], f, ensure_ascii=False)`. This code saves all the non-english characters like `u0645` or something like that .

Comment: from [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html?highlight=json%20dump#json.dump) `json.dump(obj,fp,*)`,the first parameter should be a json object.I have mentioned the answer above.you should first parse it to json object, then dump into file text